# foreach get data from variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

my input looks like this

```
array:3 [
  "year" => "2018"
  "tableData" => array:1 [
    0 => "DT_NSO_1100_008V1"
  ]
  "viewType" => "1"
]
```

and I need to get tableData's code, I used foreach but it gives me an error

```
foreach ($input['tableData'] as $key => $value) {
      $ushChildTable = UshTableCode::where('code', $value)->first();
}
```

and my error looks like this 
[image]

how to can I get these code guys?

Comment: `I used foreach but it gives me an error` ... What is the error?

Comment: `dd($input)` to see what it is.

Comment: array:3 [
  "year" => "2018"
  "tableData" => array:1 [
    0 => "DT_NSO_1100_008V1"
  ]
  "viewType" => "1"
]

this is what came out by dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using for checking whether the input for table data is empty or not

```
$tableData = $input['tableData'];

if(!empty($tableData)){
    foreach($tableData as $key => $value){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Input model class or form inputs?

Comment: the first way gives me / Illegal string offset 'tableData' / and then the second way gives me / Method first does not exist. /

Comment: yeah input is a form